# I am trying to retrieve the value of a key based on another key of a json in bash scripting without the use of jq

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a *json* file and need to retrieve the name from the *json* based on the value of *"Id"* fields in the same *json*.  I need to do this with bash scripting.  I can use `sed`, `awk`, `grep` but not `jq`.

```
[  
   {  
      "attributes":{  
         "type":"chocolate","url":"/services/chocolate"
      },
      "Id":"1",
      "Name":"Chocolaty chocloate"
   },
   {  
      "attributes":{  
         "type":"Fruit","url":"/services/fruit"
      },
      "Id":"2",
      "Name":"Fruity Apple"
   },
  {  
      "attributes":{  
         "type":"drink","url":"/services/drink"
      },
      "Id":"3",
      "Name":"Milk Shake"
   },
   {  
      "attributes":{  
         "type":"food","url":"/services/food"
      },
      "Id":"4",
      "Name":"Noodles"
   }
]
```

In the above example, if I pass value *"3"* to the script, I expect the name of the *"Id"* with the value *"3"* which is `Milk Shake`.

Comment: I'm sure you meant `jq` and not `jp`

Comment: Indeed. Do you know any way I could do this? @Inian

Comment: I would recommend using `jq` and not use non-syntax aware parsers for JSON - `awk`, `sed`

Comment: I cannot use jq because of some limitation. Thats why I am particular to not use jq

Comment: Why not using `jq`. Is it an arbitrary requirement from an assignment text?

Comment: This a part of automation and the devops tool cli doesnt support jq

Comment: Then be creative, analize and split the problem like this: What is the structure of the JSON. So you have an Array that starts with `[` has content and ends with `]`, you have objects `{`...`}`, and you have `"key":` something keyed, and raw values. Everything is nested so you have to deal with start markers, end markers and contexts. `Awk` can do, and `sed` can do. But any wrong Regex or wrong analyzing of the JSON syntax will cause your algorithm to break. So before spending a day re-inventing a JSON parser in RegEx and broke risks. I'd go back to sys admin and ask for proper tools.

Comment: I mean, re-implementing a JSON parser with the wrong tools is a true technical debt with a very real cost compared to installing `jq`, or coding a solution with a JSON aware language.

Comment: Should the output be unquoted `Milk Shake` or quoted `"Milk Shake"`?

Comment: The output should be unquoted Milk shake @agc

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is with jq. But if it's supposed to be sed, you could do it here:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -n "/\"Id\":\"$2\"/,/\"Name\"/s/.*\"Name\":\"\([^\"]*\).*/\1/p" "$1"
```

**usage**

```
script.sh file.json 3
```

**output**

```
Milk Shake
```

Comment: I tried this and It dint work. It gives no response. Is there something I need to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two lines are always next to each other, a *GNU* `grep` pipe, (in a function), works:

```
foo() { grep -A 1 '"Id":"'"$2"'",$' "$1" | grep -o '"[^"]*"$'; }
foo file.json 3
```

Output:

```
"Milk Shake"
```

Comment: Maybe `pgrep` might be able to do it in one shot, (without the pipe).

Comment: @Julia, Re *"...didn't work..."*:  Please provide the output of `grep -V | head -1 ; wc -c file.json`.

Comment: grep (GNU grep) 3.1 27787 file.json - The the output I got with that command @agc

Comment: @Julia, Thanks, given that output, I suspect that *file.json* is DOS text file.  Please provide the output of `file file.json`.

Comment: file.json: JSON data - thats the output of file file.json @agc

Comment: @Julia, Thanks, that helps, but it's still inconclusive.  Please provide the output of `wc -l < file.json`   and   `hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X "'   file.json   | grep -o  '0D 0A' | uniq -c`, and those ought to be enough.
`

Comment: @Julia, Note:  when writing comments with quoted code, (or sample of program output), so that the text has a *gray* background instead of *white*, use backticks like this `\`echo foo\``.